# How to change a text or symbol into line break in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, replace, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to change all `;` into a line break `\n` in Google Sheets.

Is there a way to automate this or I need to do it one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SUBSTITUTE` or `REGEXREPLACE` formulas wrapped in the `ARRAYFORMULA` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(your_formula_or_range_here, ";", CHAR(10))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(your_formula_or_range_here, ";", CHAR(10))
```

**example:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY({INDEX(QUERY(A1:B, 
 "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 0), , 1), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(QUERY(A1:B, 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 0)), INDEX(QUERY({A1:A,B1:B&";"},
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 offset 1", 0), 1,), ))
 , , 999^99))), ";$", )}, "offset 1", 0), "; ", CHAR(10)))
```

[image: 0]